# Sending large number of emails with attachments in Cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am using CakeEmail to sent about 7000 emails in a loop. But when I sent emails with small attachments of about (1kb) its working fine. But when I use bigger attcahment files such as of size 800kb it just quite after sending some emails may be 23 or 60. But not completing the process.

The Page quits by giving a message "This webpage is not available"

The code is in a loop where each CakeEmail is initialized to sent to an email address

I tried using

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

But it didnt work.

Can anyone helps me out why its not able send using an attachment of 800kb ?

Answer (score 1):

Some shared servers do not allow to run longer scripts, thus not allowing to override the time limit.

Might be you can do something to send 10 emails at a time and then redirect the browser to the same page to send another 10. Just fetch the specific 10 emails using DB LIMIT clause.

Or you can also create a cron job to run the script through shell.

PS - kindly provide the code you are using so I can help in modifying it

Comment: But when I sent 7000 emails with 100kb attachments, it just sent out successfully. It took about 15 min to send all the emails. So its not the execution time right?

Comment: Is it a shared server? what RAM you have on it?

Comment: Just check maximum upload allowed. Refer to this page http://www.helpspot.com/helpdesk/index.php?pg=kb.page&id=34

Comment: Okay but I am saving that file to the server before clicking the button send

Comment: What is your mail engine handler? Perhaps the server is setup to drop traffic after a limit. Spam filters try to detect staff like thousands of emails, then size of email attachments, size of total requests in the past period, etc. One rule may pass but combined fail. You can try a ``sleep(1)`` between emails and see if it increases your limit or even another service like a bulk email SMTP provider.